# Google Maps Android No Cluster/DeCluster on Zoom In/Out

Tags: google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-utils

I have implemented Google Maps Clustering on the iOS version of my app and it works fine.  I am now attempting to implement Clustering on the Android version using the android maps utility library and it is not Declustering/Clustering when I zoom in or out.

Here is the cluster item class:

```
public class MyClusterItem implements ClusterItem {

    private final LatLng position;
    private final BitmapDescriptor icon;
    private final String tag;

    public MyClusterItem(double lat, double lng, BitmapDescriptor icon, String tag) {
        this.position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        this.icon = icon;
        this.tag = tag;
    }
    @Override
    public LatLng getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSnippet() {
        return null;
    }

    public BitmapDescriptor getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }
}
```

Here is how the cluster manager is implemented:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        //Log.i ( TAG, "Google Map Ready Callback" );
        mMap = googleMap;
        //mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
        // Point the map's listeners at the listeners implemented by the cluster
        // manager.
        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && isLocationEnabled) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
        float mCurrentZoom = googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
        // Initialize the manager with the context and the map.
        // (Activity extends context, so we can pass 'this' in the constructor.)
        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyClusterItem>(this, mMap);
        mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(mClusterItemClickListener);
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
        mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<MyClusterItem>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClusterClick(final Cluster<MyClusterItem> cluster) {
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                        cluster.getPosition(), (float) Math.floor(mMap
                                .getCameraPosition().zoom + 1)), 300,
                        null);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Cluster Items are added from a Firebase database as follows:

```
markerRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
      try {
         tableCount = tableCount+1;
         markerKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
         markerData = dataSnapshot.getValue(Markers.class);
         MyClusterItem markerItem = new PicNickClusterItem(markerData.y, markerData.x,      BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.verified), markerKey);
         mClusterItemMap.put(markerKey, markerItem);
         mClusterManager.addItem(markerItem);
         if(tableCount >= numTables) {
            //cluster markers
            mClusterManager.cluster();
         }
      } catch (Error error) {
         noFirebaseAccessAlert();
      }
   }
}
```

Screenshot of the initial map:

[image]

Screenshot when zoomed out:

[image]

Screenshot when zoomed in:

[image]

Cluster Items are not being clustered/declustered when zooming out/in and there is no animation.  As I zoom out I would expect the cluster items to move into clusters and as I zoom in Cluster Items to separate from clusters as they do in the iOS version of the app. Also when I tap on a cluster marker, the map zooms in, but the cluster does not expand into cluster items.  None of the cluster items have the same lat/lng and are separated by significant distances.

In the iOS version I was able to set the algorithm (non hierarchical distance based) & several "buckets" for clustering (and specify custom icons for each).  I need to have both versions looks and respond the same so that the user has the same experience on both iOS and Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

I  had the same issue, that markerItems were not dec-clustered when zoomming in, even to the maximum zoom level of 21.
The reason was that the CameraIdleListener was not setup corectly. My listener was setup as:

```
   mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager);
    mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener(){
        public void onCameraIdle(){...} });
```

By the following setup markerItems were de-clustered by zooming in:

```
     mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener(){
        public void onCameraIdle(){
            do something
            mClusterManager.onCameraIdle();
        }
    });
```